# How to extend Angularjs ng-include directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-include

I am trying to extend the `ng-include` directive with this:

```
module.directive('incComp', [function () {
    return {
        template: "<div ng-include=\"'app/component/{{incComp}}/template.html'\"></div>"
    };
}]);
```

and I use it like this:

```
    <div inc-comp="counter"></div>
```

but the get request that goes out is for:

```
/app/component/%7B%7BincComp%7D%7D/template.html
```

I'm not sure how to get it insert the value of the inc-comp attribute rather than just using the literal value in the template string. I got the notion of doing this from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23413368/modifying-ng-include-directive) SO question (2nd answer).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The task can also be done without **ng-include** and without **isolated-scope**, a good **solution** i think:

[plnk demo here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Jc0Yk8ZDlG3HmcuSeIqn?p=preview)

*index.html*

```
  <div ng-app="app" ng-controller="appCtrl">
    <div add-template type="lion"></div>
    <div add-template type="fox"></div>
  </div>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.14/angular.js" data-semver="1.3.14"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var app = angular.module("app", []); 
    app.directive('addTemplate', function() {
      return {
        templateUrl: function(elem, attr) {
          return 'template_' + attr.type + '.html';
        }
      }
    });
  </script>
```

*template_fox.html*

```
<div> This is Fox Template </div>
```

*template_lion.html*

```
<div> This is Lion Template </div>
```

Happy Helping!

Comment: I forgot you could do that.

Answer (score 3):

`incComp` is evaluated to nothing in your template. You need to add it to your scope. And ng-include takes an expression, not a template. Something like this should work better:

```
module.directive('incComp', [function () {
    return {
        scope: true,
        controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
            $scope.tpl = 'app/component/' + $attrs.incComp + '/template.html'
        },
        template: "<div ng-include=\"tpl\"></div>"
    };
}]);
```

You could also do that in the link function instead of the controller.

I didn't test it though...

EDIT: I suppose you could also do something like this:

```
module.directive('incComp', [function () {
    return {
        scope: {
            incComp: '@'
        },
        template: "<div ng-include=\"'app/component/' + incComp + '/template.html'\"></div>"
    };
}]);
```

Comment: Those 2 ways end up with the same result, but they have different pros and cons. One creates a controller, the other one creates an isolate scope...